# How to record bag-file for hector-mapping

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I've tried to record a .bag-File for creating a map with hector_slam_launch.
A Hokuyo UBG-04LX-F01 is used for this - the datastream is running and mapped to "/scan"
I've no other sensors at the test-system so I used the configuration-params from the Hector-Slamp-Tutorial for using without odom-frame.

The roscore and hokuyo_node are running - what else should be running during recording the bag-file?

If I try to use one of mine bag-files I get the following error-message in the hector_slam_launch terminal:

```
lookupTransform base_frame to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
```

Maybe someone knows whats wrong with my approach..

Thanks!, Armin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12575/how-to-record-bag-file-for-hector-mapping/) by [Armin Hopf](https://answers.ros.org/users/1625/armin-hopf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you use slam, it's going to try to convert the laser scan from the frame_id of the sensor to the base_frame of your robot. As such, you must provide the transformation from your robot's base_frame to the sensor's frame. This can be done with a `static_transform` if the transformation is static, or a `transform_broadcaster` if it's not static. Both of these can be found in the [tf tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3